# Superadditivity of convex set

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, game-theory

If $f:2^{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb R _+$ is convex and nondecreasing, and is defined over the set $\Omega$ and $f(\varnothing) = 0$, is $f$ superadditive?

The convexity of $f$ is defined as,

$$f(S\cup T) + f(S\cap T) \geq f(S) + f(T), ~~~~\forall S, T \subseteq \Omega$$

Superadditivity is defined by,

$$f(S\cup T) \geq f(S) + f(T), ~~~~\forall S, T \subseteq \Omega$$

Comment: For the usual definition of superadditivity $S$ and $T$ should be restricted to disjoint sets. And a more conventional name for convexity of $f$ is supermodularity (equivalent to the concavity of its Lovász extension)

Comment: Can you share any reference?

Comment: Well, Wikipedia. Superadditivity is a common assumption in coalition games, so a reference would be Owen's "Game Theory". Supermodularity is sometimes studied in non-cooperative games, and is discussed in Fudenberg and Tirole's "Game Theory".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Define $\Omega = \{1\}$ and $f(\{1\}) = 1$. It is easy to check that $f$ is convex but not superadditive.

Comment: I didn't get it. Please elaborate.

Comment: $f(\lbrace 1 \rbrace \cup \lbrace \varnothing \rbrace) \geq f(\lbrace 1 \rbrace) + f(\lbrace \varnothing \rbrace) $, because, $f(\lbrace \varnothing \rbrace) = 0$.

Comment: @Eval $2^\Omega$ only contains the sets $\varnothing$ and $\{1\}$, so you can just check out all combinations and find that $f$ is convex but not superadditive. For example $$f(\{1\}\cup\{1\})=f(\{1\})=1\not\ge2=1+1=f(\{1\})+f(\{1\}),$$hence not superadditive.